# Trim just white space, without escape characters

Tags: c#

Here is my string:

```
"\tsome text\t\t\t\t"
```

And when I do:

```
"\tsome text\t\t\t\t".Trim()
```

the \t are also deleted. How to avoid this?

Comment: `also deleted` - aren't they the _only_ things deleted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"\tsome text\t\t\t\t".Trim(' ')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you write:

```
string x = "\tsome text\t\t\t\t";
```

the string doesn't actually contain "backslash t" anywhere. It contains tab characters, which are whitespace. `Trim()` trims whitespace, so it removes the tabs.

It's important that you understand that `"\t"` is *just* a source code representation of tab. By the time the code is executing, the string has no knowledge of where its data came from - it just knows that there are tabs.

Now if you want to trim just *some* whitespace characters, use [the overload which allows you to specify which characters to trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

`Trim()` will trim all white-space characters (' ', \t, \v, \r, \n, \f) from your string. If you only want to trim spaces from your string you could do this:

> `Trim(' ')`

Or if you wanted to trim spaces, carriage return and line feeds you could do this:

> `Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' })`