# Stop C# string.Trim() removing FF character?

Tags: c#, string, special-characters

Is there any way of stopping `string.Trim()` from removing an [FF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) character?

I am parsing a file wanrt to be able to tell the difference between an empty line with just an FF char, a line of spaces with an FF char, and a line of "data" with an FF char.

However, if I test `string.Trim() == string.Empty` then it returns true for all of:

```
"\f"
"                               "
"                             \f"
```

e.g. It is also trimming the `\f` out of the string?

Note: I *can* test for the `\f` using Regex, but interested in why the trim removes the \f as well?

Comment: did you try this ? Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' })

Comment: Possible duplicate  :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304536/trim-just-white-space-without-escape-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSDN:

string.trim

> White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard. The Trim() method removes any leading and trailing characters that produce a return value of true when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

From Char.IsWhiteSpace

> White space characters are the following Unicode characters: The characters CHARACTER TABULATION (U+0009), LINE FEED (U+000A), LINE TABULATION (U+000B), FORM FEED (U+000C), CARRIAGE RETURN (U+000D), NEXT LINE (U+0085), and NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx

That's why it's getting stripped out.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Because it is designed to remove it. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)